# How to shadow over a div that needs to be clickable?

Tags: html, css

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8I8P.png)

I am trying to create a hidden submenu that appears to be underneath my main content.  I have successfully got the appearance of this working, although the links within the submenu  are not functional do to the z-index.

I can solve this by simply indexing the sidebar above the content, but that breaks my shadow effect, and vice versa.

The way I am currently generating my shadow:

```
.sidebar-is-expanded .l-main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 220px;
  right: 0;
}
```

Which albeit works, it seems there would be a better solution to achieve this.

I have then indexed my main content `.l-main {z-index: 19;}` to above the sidebar content `.l-sidebar {z-index: 18;}`, because the shadow wasn't displaying otherwise.  Doing this is what "*breaks*" the sidebar navigation.

**< Addition note >**

I am aware I could add a shadow to the right side of the sidebar rather than the bottom of the content, although in all my attempts to do it this way I found I needed to add the shadow in multiple spots and certain spots would not work (*when the full code is in place*).  So I thought it has to be easier to apply a single shadow to the content container rather than multiple sidebar elements, and well... here we are.

**< / Addition note >**

I have created a striped down pen to demonstrate what is going on [HERE](https://codepen.io/-GiR/pen/wvWRqpr?editors=1100)

This is my stylesheet striped the best I could while maintaining the functionality I need for demonstration.

```
.omnibar .community-nav .navbar-nav > li > a.link-admin:hover {
  background-color: #D5441F;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.u-list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-is-expanded .omnibar {
  left: 220px;
}

.l-sidebar {
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #383838;
  visibility: hidden;
      width: 0px;
  z-index: 18;
}

.l-sidebar__content {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.sidebar-is-expanded .l-sidebar {
  width: 220px;
  visibility: visible;
}

main.l-main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 19;
  overflow: auto;
    
}

.sidebar-is-expanded .l-main:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 220px;
  right: 0;
}

.sidebar-is-expanded main.l-main {
  padding-left: 220px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li:before { 
  background-color: #D5441F;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 3px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.first {
  background-color: #D5441F;
  color: #ffffff;
}


.sidebar-nav li:first-child a:hover {
  background-color: #D5441F;
}

.sidebar-nav li:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
    
}

.sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #525252;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:hover,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:active,
.sidebar-nav li.open a:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Here is my HTML stripped down allowing this functionality:

```
<body class="sidebar-is-reduced">
  <div class="l-sidebar">
    <div class="l-sidebar__content">
      <nav class="c-menu js-menu">
        <ul class="u-list sidebar-nav">
          <li class="first"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-folder"></i> Page one</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file-o"></i> Second page</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i> Third page</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<main class="l-main">
  <div class="page-container"><div class="page">
      <div class="page-content">
        <div class="navbar-wrapper">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default omnibar ">
            <div class='container-fluid community-nav'><ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown"><a data-effect="st-effect-3" href='#' class="link-admin">Sidebar</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href='' >Link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            CONTENT
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="page-footer">FOOTER</footer>
    </div></div>
</main>
```

How can I properly shadow **over** a div that I need to be able to click while maintaining my current structure?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please always add a minimal reproducable code snippet. Just giving CSS code lines without corresponding HTMl is quite useless. As such we can not reproduce the issue and have a hard time to help you to fix it. Besides of that, a code snippet helps to clarify the issue at hand.

Comment: Rather than adding the entire code (while keeping this functionality working) I created a demo because the the source for this was quite extensive to be posted.  I thought maybe this was answerable with the code I did provide.  I have however added it to the original post now.